# How do I add a column which 'differences out' a cumulative variable by category?

Tags: python, pandas

My first time posting so bear with me. I have a COVID dataset that looks like this:

```
date        | county | confirmed
2021-05-01    Bexar     1200
2021-05-01    Travis    1500
2021-05-01    Harris    1300
2021-05-02    Bexar     1250
2021-05-02    Travis    1550
2021-05-02    Harris    1350
```

Where the 'confirmed' column is cumulative.

In reality it's a much bigger dataset (several dates and over 200 counties).  I want to add a column to the dataset which gives the difference (new cases) each day, by the county.  So that it ends up like:

```
date        | county | confirmed  | new_cases 
2021-05-01    Bexar     1200         N/A
2021-05-01    Travis    1500         N/A
2021-05-01    Harris    1300         N/A
2021-05-02    Bexar     1250         50
2021-05-02    Travis    1530         30
2021-05-02    Harris    1340         40
```

I've tried figuring out how to loop the df.diff() command over county, and adding the result to the df each time.  But I'm so new to Python that I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working with `pandas`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])

df['diff'] = df.groupby(['county'])['confirmed'].diff().fillna(0)
```